# Trying to post more than one variable via xmlhttprequest of ajax to the controller

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

In my java application. I am trying to post more two javascript variable to via a xmlhttp post request of ajax but it is returning error 400. Ordinarily, if I comment out one of the post variables, then it posts successfully but on adding it, throws error. This is my attempt:

```
function sendChat() {
        var message = document.getElementById('new-input').value.trim();
        var noteVal = "mp3",
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ....

        alert(noteVal);
        xhr.send(encodeURI('message=' + message));
        xhr.send(encodeURI('noteVal=' + noteVal)); //if I comment this out then everything is fine
    }
```

this is the spring controller to receive the post arguments

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView postData(HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response,
                           @RequestParam String message,
                           @RequestParam String noteVal,
```

Please how can I post more than one variables to the controller method via XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only send once, so you send both values

```
xhr.send('message=' + encodeURI(message) + '&noteVal=' + encodeURI(noteVal));
```

or sending formData

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('message', message);
data.append('noteVal', noteVal);

xhr.send(data);
```